# NullReferenceException with object initializer suggested by resharper

Tags: c#, initialization, resharper, c#-6.0

I have a strange issue with the object initializer syntax.

Here are my sample classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bah BahProp { get; set; }
}

public class Bah
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Consider following three ways to initialize an object:

The old, verbose but explicit way, working correctly:

```
var foo1 = new Foo();
foo1.BahProp = new Bah();
foo1.BahProp.Id = 1;
// correctly initialized
```

The second way i'm  always using, using [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax:

```
var foo2 = new Foo
{
    BahProp = new Bah { Id = 1 }
}; // correctly initialized
```

A third way resharper has suggested my collegue with a different resharper version(is it a bug?):

```
var foo3 = new Foo
{
    BahProp = { Id = 1 }
};  // NullReferenceException
```

What is the last approach doing differently?

My resharper version is 2016.1.1, my colleague was on 10.02. My resharper suggested the second way. But what does the third way do and when is it useful?

**Update**: So it seems that it was a bad resharper sugestion to use the last way, that's why they have changed it meanwhile to use the second way.

You can avoid the `NullReferenceException` if you want to use the third way by initializing all properties/fields that are reference types inline or in the constructor.

I will definitely not use this strange property assignment syntax.

Comment: I would check the compiled .dll with ILSpy or any other decompiler to see what the compiler did differently

Comment: *"I will definitely not use this strange property assignment syntax"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
new Foo { BahProp = { Id = 1 } }
```

compiles to:

```
new Foo().BahProp.Id = 1;
```

or, little more verbose:

```
var foo3 = new Foo();
foo3.BahProp.Id = 1;
```

So BahProp is null. You're not *constructing* it.
(This is perhaps the most confusing syntax in all of C#)
Option 2 works because you're calling the constructor of Bah.

Option 3 would also work if you initialize BahProp inside the constructor of Foo. It will have been constructed by the time `BahProp = { Id = 1 }` is called.

The same is seen with collection initializers:

```
public class Foo {
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
}

var foo = new Foo { Numbers = { 1, 2, 3 } };
```

This does not initialize the List. It only calls Add on it.

You really must see `new MyObject() { X = 1, Y = 2 }` as two distinct parts:
`new MyObject()` constructs a new object and
`{ X = 1, Y = 2 }` sets the values of its properties (and that's all it does).
Object and collection initializers can be nested. The top-level initializer must follow a constructor, but a nested initializer does not.

Comment: Thanks. Note that i've modified my bah class since the type of the property doesn't matter. It doesn't need to be a reference to each other. If `{ Id = 1 }` does not call the default constructor of `Bah` implicitely, when is it useful at all? Do you have a link to MSDN?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think you can find this particular case on MSDN. I just tried it out on http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: but this initializer syntax must be documented somewhere: `BahProp = { Id = 1 }`. Or is is not an initializer syntax but only a strange property assignment. I'm afraid it's still not clear.

Comment: All `{ SomeProperty = someValue }` does is set the value of SomeProperty.  It just allows you to do it all in one statement. It does not call any constructor implicitly.

Comment: So the correct way was to initialize all fields/properties which are reference types in the constructor.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Look at the collection initializer. I've seen it a few times. The List is usually initialized in the constructor. If you initialize BlahProp in the constructor, too, it will work (or use option 2). But, yeah it's still pretty weird.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it better. i think the '=' is the thing causing confusion; it means 2 different things. In `BlahProp = {x}` it means: "Set BlahProp's properties to x". (whatever x is) It's `BlahProp`'s initializer. In `BlahProp = new Bla() {Id=1}` it's just an assignment, like any other variable. The object initializer is not `BlahProp`'s initializer, but the new Bla's initializer.

Comment: Thanks. I think i've got the point. It's not an initializer syntax but just a way to initialize properties in one statement. It always requires the reference-type property to be initialized before, best by using the constructor. I think i'll avoid that syntax anyway.

Comment: Yup, that's all it does: initialize properties in one statement. It is usually advertized and used *in combination with* calling a constructor (`new Bla() {...}`), but it is not required. It *does* allow you to chain a bunch of  initializers together.

Comment: The approach that uses an explicit `BahProp = new Bah{Id = 1}` is what i always uses and it's working fine in any case. But the `BahProp = { Id = 1 }` is the confusing way which can cause `NullReferenceExceptions` at runtime.

Comment: In `Numbers = {1,2,3}` and `BlahProp = {...}`, the '=' is not really an assignment operator. I think that's the reason it looks really weird.

Comment: The examples on MSDN do use nested intializers, but they are all paired with constructors, e.g. `List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat> { new Cat(){ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 }, ... }`. They don't explain this particular situation.