# 'Cannot initialize type with a collection initializer' while initializing object of my class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, initialization

I have a very weird problem.

Here's a class I defined:

```
public class HeaderTagControlsPair
{
    public TextBlock HeaderTextBlock = new TextBlock();
    public ComboBox TagComboBox = new ComboBox();
    public RowDefinition Row = new RowDefinition();
}
```

Now, I want to create an object of this class and initialize it:

```
    HeaderTagControlsPair example = new HeaderTagControlsPair
    {
        HeaderTextBlock.Text = "test"
    };
```

I can't do it. I get those three errors:

```
Error   1   Cannot initialize type 'CSV_To_Tags_App.HeaderTagControlsPair' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
Error   2   Invalid initializer member declarator   
Error   3   The name 'HeaderTextBlock' does not exist in the current context
```

I have no idea why it happens, I'm just using simple object initialization. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At least one of those errors happen because you access `Text` property of `HeaderTextBlock` without initializing it. Consider trying `HeaderTagControlsPair example = new HeaderTagControlsPair();` then setting the individual values afterwards, or declaring a new `TextBlock` element using "test" string (e.g. **tb**) and setting `HeaderTextBlock.Text = tb` in the declaration instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize (public) fields or properties with the [object initializer syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). In this case the `HeaderTextBlock` property. But you cannot initialize properties of these types. So you need a nested object initializer for the `Text` property.

Either this:

```
HeaderTagControlsPair example = new HeaderTagControlsPair
{
    HeaderTextBlock = new TextBlock {Text = "test"}
};
```

or shorter in C#6:

```
HeaderTagControlsPair example = new HeaderTagControlsPair
{
    HeaderTextBlock = { Text = "test" }
};
```

(i prefer the first version to prevent strange issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369967/nullreferenceexception-with-object-initializer-suggested-by-resharper))

Answer (score 2):

It should be (C#6):

```
HeaderTagControlsPair example = new HeaderTagControlsPair
{
     HeaderTextBlock = {Text = "test" }
};
```

Comment: Why is that? I had never seen this type of initialization. I followed this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx